# Get address using Geocoder in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I tried to get the address of a particular location by giving static geocordinates. I was not able to fetch the address. Can someone please help. I just need to check whether this function works for me.

Here is my snippet.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(AddressSimulator.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(1.352566007, 103.78921587, 1);
        System.out.println("Addresses size"+addresses.size());
```

Address size is obtained as zero. I tried with few other geocordinates also, but address size is always returned as 0. Experts, kindly help me resolve this.

Looking forward for your valuable help/suggestions,

Best Regards,
Rony

Comment: Just on a slightly different note, are you getting an exception like "Service Not Available" ??

Comment: Well Rony the lat, long you have used is somewhere in the wilderness in france. Try again with seatlle or something

Answer (score 3):

Try the one from google or from rpc geocoder. For google maps you have to get a key from google.

for geocoder they respond for only one request in every 15 sec from the same ip.

```
string geocoderUri = String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q={0},{1},{2}&output=csv"
                + "&key= < Your Key > ", street, city, state);
```

or

```
string geocoderUri = string.Format("http://rpc.geocoder.us/service/rest?address={0},{1},{2}", street, city, state);
```

Comment: Hi franklins, thanks for the reply...but how do i get street, city, state when I only have latitude and longitude?

Comment: This may help: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding Generaly what your trying to do is called reverse-geocoding, so you can look for that for help.

Comment: what are street,city and state here. I kept them as String but they are not accepting

Comment: string geocoderUri = string.Format("http://rpc.geocoder.us/service/rest?address={0},{1},{2}", "1 Main St", "Queens", "NY");

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. It will provide you the street, area, country name. 
Also see this doc; here you can find more methods.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

```
try {

            Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
                addres.setText("Waiting for Location");
            }
            else {
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    addres.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() +", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address:- " + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + addresses.get(0).getLocality(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // getFromLocation() may sometimes fail
        }
```

Hope this will help....

Comment: He's using static coordinates, not waiting for location updates. I know his problem because I'm having it also. Simply can't get any address. No one promised every set of coordinates will return an address, I'm guessing this is the problem in my case, may be in his also.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the INTERNET security permissions set in your AndroidManifest.xml.  You need the INTERNET permission to do the lookup.  I know you're doing a static lat,long lookup but if you want to do get lat and long from GPS, you'll also need to add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to enable the GPS.