# How to get city name ontap on the map in google map android v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, coordinates, android-maps-v2

By tapping on the map, How can I get the address of that location. On tap at particular location we can able listen and pass those co-ordinates we can get address but it should make work in android Google map v2.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: place a marker on tap and read out the LatLng of the marker. This way the user can see his exact point of click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your LatLng data - it's quite easy. You need to use [Goecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).

```
    protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder =
                new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        // Get the current location from the input parameter list
        Location loc = params[0];
        // Create a list to contain the result address
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            /*
             * Return 1 address.
             */
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e("LocationSampleActivity",
                "IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return ("IO Exception trying to get address");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
        // Error message to post in the log
        String errorString = "Illegal arguments " +
                Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) +
                " , " +
                Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) +
                " passed to address service";
        Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorString);
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return errorString;
        }
        // If the reverse geocode returned an address
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            // Get the first address
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            /*
             * Format the first line of address (if available),
             * city, and country name.
             */
            String addressText = String.format(
                    "%s, %s, %s",
                    // If there's a street address, add it
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ?
                            address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    // Locality is usually a city
                    address.getLocality(),
                    // The country of the address
                    address.getCountryName());
            // Return the text
            return addressText;
        } else {
            return "No address found";
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

}

The best way to do it is to use AsyncTask. You will find complete example at Android Devlopers' site: http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

Comment: this solution helped me to fix arrayIndexoutofbound exception thanks alot @adek

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-reverse-geocoding-at-touched-location-in-google-map-android-api-v2/) may help you to use the complete map opertion

Comment: Thanks its worked fine: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-reverse-geocoding-at-touched-location-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the android [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). With `GoogleMaps` v2 you can [use longpress](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/google-maps-android-api-v2-example_3.html) to get a `LatLng` point. By taking those coordinates and passing them to the `GeoCoder` you can "reverse geocode" to find the address.

Comment: The link to the longpress example has code. [Here's a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683966/get-address-using-geocoder-in-android) from S/O with a geocoder example. If you google reverse geocoder or get address from coordinate and android you will find a number of examples.

Comment: The same am using in my application getting indexoutofbound exception. I Posted code in the same page above.

Comment: Now error was fixed by adding this line: if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty())

Comment: I would not have caught that since you didn't post any code ;) glad you fixed it though